# on keyup, update meta description

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below working code fetch all meta tags from head and displays the text inside a div on a web page. On keyup, i would like to copy input text val and replace head meta description and also update div so I can see that the text has been entered correctly from the front-end.

http://jsfiddle.net/michelm/JCWgA/

Two things that I am having issue with:

1. copying the new value of the input text box and replace the "content" of the meta name="description" content="new text added" (inside the div)
2. copy the val of the input text box and replace 'content' of the head meta description

Some of the code below:

```
 <h2>Meta Description</h2>
    <!-- I have head meta tags inside the below div to read the tags on the web page -->
    <div class="all">some text</div>

<!-- input text on keyup to 1. update head meta description, 2 update meta description inside the div (<div class="all">some text</div>) -->

<input type="text" name="metadescription" id="metadescription" />

<!-- this part of jquery is working -->
<script type="text/javascript">

var foo = '';

$("head meta").each(function () {
    foo += $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
});

//alert(foo); 
var b = $('.all').text(foo);


// the below is part is not quite working
$description = $('.all').find('meta[name=description]').attr('content');

$('#metadescription').keyup(function(){
  //  $('.all').find($description).text($(this).val());
    //the below just replace all the text, but I want it to replace the 'content'
    $('.all').text($(this).val());
    //alert(foo); 



});

</script>
```

I got this to work, a big part goes to thanking softsdev for the most of the code :))

*** Below is the FULL working code!!!! **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="description" content="This is the meta description of some sort" >
<meta name="keywords" content="some, content, added" >
<title>change meta content</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $('.content').keyup(function(){
            $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', $(this).val());
        });


    });

</script>
</head>

<body>



    <h2>Meta Description</h2>

<div class="all">some text</div>
    <h4>Update meta description</h4>
<input type="text" name="content"  class="content"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.content').keyup(function(){

    $('.all').text('<meta name="description" content="'+$(this).val()+'">');

});


$('.all').append(($('meta[name=descritption]').attr('content')));
var tt = jQuery.metadata.get(name=descritption)
   $('.all').text(tt);
   $('meta[name=description]').attr('description').insertAfter('body');
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
if (document.getElementsByName) {

  var metaArray = document.getElementsByName('description');
  for (var i=0; i<metaArray.length; i++) {
   // document.write(metaArray[i].content + '<br>');
            $('.all').text('<meta name="description" content="'+ metaArray[i].content +'">' );

  }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JCWgA/1/

Comment: woaw:) you are awesome dude!

Comment: @softsdev Why not just answer the question? (so it doesn't show up in the "unanswered" section)

Comment: would you know how can I append this value to the head as well? I tried: $('head').append('<meta name="description" content="'+$(this).val()+'">');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JCWgA/1)

change

```
$('.all').text($(this).val());
```

with

```
$('.all').text('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="'+$(this).val()+'">');
```

**Updated Answer**

if you want to do it in your html then you can try this and check in firebug content will change of meta tag

but it will reflect only on client side

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="description" content="This is the meta description of some sort" >
<meta name="keywords" content="some, content, added" >
<title>change meta content</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $('.content').keyup(function(){
            $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', $(this).val());
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="content"  class="content"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you know how can I append this value to the head as well? I tried: $('head').append('<meta name="description" content="'+$(this).val()+'">');

Comment: Nice one mate, I added more code to target only meta description, that's a keeper!